# postcss loader with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, postcss-loader

I'm trying to use `postcss-loader` plugin with webpack, but I can't understand how to use it, in my output build I doesn't have a css file and a js file but only a js file, and the css inside the builded js.

This is the my-container.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import "./container.scss";

class MyContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my-container">...</div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyContainer;
```

this is the container.scss file:

```
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 2147483000;
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import MyContainer from "./my-container";

ReactDOM.render(<MyContainer/>, document.getElementById("demo"));
```

This is my webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "build": "./src/index.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" }, { loader: "sass-loader" }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "[name].[hash].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

I have checked the css in the js file and there isn't any vendor prefixes, for example in my scss code there is `display: flex;` that must generate some prefixes, anyone can tell me how setup it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You import a file with a `.scss` extension:

```
import "./container.scss";
```

`webpack` will then **only** apply the loaders that match the `.scss` extension.

```
// ...
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" }, { loader: "sass-loader" }]
},
// ...
```

You're expecting `webpack` to also apply the rules of `.css` but it is not receiving files with the `.css` extension, so it can not transform it.

You need check if you're in a development environment (and need to inject the css in js with `style-loader`) or production (and need to extract the css with `MiniCssExtractPlugin`). [This part](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#advanced-configuration-example) of the webpack docs give an example how to do exactly that.